# How to read a matrix from a file? (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

---

I've been trying a bunch of stuff and tried searching solutions but nothing I do works. This is not even a difficult thing to do but for the life of me I can' do it.

Basically I have a .txt file generated by Matlab that's a 640*480 matrix. Each cell has 2 values separated by a coma.

I want to read from that file to create a 640*480 2D array that contains my 2 values so that I can access the cells fast to get those 2 values.

Basically what i'm doing is a bit of image analysis on matlab and each pixel of the image gives 2 values that I'll use later. I save my 640*480 matrix into a .txt file.

When it's done i manually transfer that file into my c++ folder. My c++ code tracks the position (center coordinates) of a tag. I want to access that file with c++ code so that I can create my array in c++ and then access the cells to use the 2 values in them to display them on an image (only the cell that corresponds to the tag's center coordinates).

P.S: I'm thinking that the reason I can't make it work it's because of the coma that separates the 2 values, but I have no idea how to work around that.

Just to get you a clearer idea about what my matrix looks like:

```
1,1     1,2     1,3     1,4

2,1     2,2     2,3     2,4

3,1     3,2     3,3     3,4

4,1     4,2     4,3     4,4
```

Comment: Please show us the "bunch of stuff".

Comment: One approach is: Read a line from file into stringstream. Read a number, a comma, a number, 3 spaces, ... from stringstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution is to use a Proxy class. An abstraction for your Cell.

If you have a Cell, consisting of 2 values, then we will define a class with 2 values and overwrite the inserter and extractor operator for this class. Only the class should know, how to read and write its data.

The extractor for reading something, like "1,2" is fairly simple. It is

```
stream >> value1 >> c >> value2;
```

So, we extract an integer, then a comma and then again an integer. So, really simple. And, because the file is generated by Matlab, we rely on the correct input format.

So, by splitting big problems into smaller problems, we find easier solutions.

Next, if we have a complete line like `1,1     1,2     1,3     1,4`, how to read that. If your replace the `x,y` by `s`n, then you could write

```
stream >> s1 >> s2 >> s3 >> s3;
```

But if the number of elements are unknown, then we need to ietarte over all values. For this we have the `std::istream_iterator`. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). It basically calls the extractor operator `>>` for a given type, as long as input is available. So, if the type is `Cell` it will call `>> cell[n]` repeatedly.

If we define a `std::vector`, we can use its range constructor to fill the `std::vector`. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) about constructor number 5. The start iterator will be the constructor of the `std::istream_operator` and the end iterator will be the default constructed `std::istream_iterator` via `{}`. See [Constructor number 1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator).

This will result in:

```
std::vector<Cell> lineVector(std::istream_iterator<Cell>(lineStream), {})
```

Please note, we use a typedef (using) for ```` std::vector<Cell>```= ````CV```` this make writing simpler. With that, we get:

```
CV lineVector(std::istream_iterator<Cell>(lineStream), {})
```

OK, now we have a complete parsed line.

Additionaly we have a resulting `std::vector`, which contains all of the above data.

To add a such a parsed line to resulting "cells"-vector, we could now use the `push_back` function. But we can better use the `emplace_back` function, to avoid the temporary line vector and do an inplace construction.

All this together will end up in:

```
cells.emplace_back(CV(std::istream_iterator<Cell>(lineStream), {}));
```

So, we will have a very simple mechanism to parse the complete file.

Please see below a concrete solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::istringstream testStream{R"(1,1     1,2     1,3     1,4
2,1     2,2     2,3     2,4
3,1     3,2     3,3     3,4
4,1     4,2     4,3     4,4)"};

// Proxy class to abstract a Cell
struct Cell {

    int value1{};
    int value2{};

    // Overwrite exctractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Cell& c) {
        char comma;
        return is >> c.value1 >> comma >> c.value2;
    }
    // Overwrite inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Cell& c) {
        return os << c.value1 << ',' << c.value2;
    }
};

using CV = std::vector<Cell>;

int main() {

    // The target data
    std::vector<CV> cells{};

    // Read and parse complete source file. 
    // Readd all lines of the source file
    for (std::string line{}; std::getline(testStream, line); ) {

        // Put the line into a stringstream
        std::istringstream lineStream{ line };

        // Parse the line data and add the result to our cells vector
        cells.emplace_back(CV(std::istream_iterator<Cell>(lineStream), {}));
    }


    // Show result on console
    // Go through all lines
    for (const CV& cv : cells) {
        // Go through all columns
        for (const Cell& c : cv) std::cout << c << '\t';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note: We have in main only 3 lines doing all the work.

If you have more questions, then please ask.

Comment: I tested it and adapted it to read my file and it works thank you. I had another program that seemed to work but not for all my file. My have has 640 lines and 480 columns but I couldn't read more than 640x404 for some reason, over that it would not run

Comment: just to make sure, when you say "overwrite", you mean "overload" the operator? or is it something else

Comment: Yes, I mean overload. Sorry, a little bit mixed with the new override key word. Regarding your other problem. Please put ````static```` in front if the vector definition. Then the data will be stored on the heap. Maybe you run into problems with stack size. Please try.

Comment: The problem isn't with what's here on your answer, it's on what I tried to do on my own before. I didn't use vectors on what I tried.